# How to convert Exponent type of data to number format in Excel.?

Tags: excel

Exponent data like (8.53938421771233E-05) . i want to copy data from excel to column of decimal(18,6) but there are thousands of records with exponent values which are supposed to be converted. Was doing it manually.

Can any one in this group help me in giving any suggestion on how to change E-data in Excel to Number format.  any suggestion will be  appreciated.

Thanks
Siddu

Comment: Look at this tutorial on that subject https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1725-excel-convert-scientific-notation-to-text.html

Comment: Select all the cells and change the format to number with 15 decimal places.

Comment: Just following up on Rons suggestion, are all the numbers in the same order of magnitude?  ie are they all E-5 or are some E-15, E-2, E9.  Also is that a typo in your number?  die you mean (18,6) or (8,6), or was your example number supposed to be (18.53938421771233E-5)?

Comment: Thanks for sugestions but there are some numbers are like E-7, E-8,E-11